# Display symbols in browser via shiny package R

Tags: r, symbols, shiny

I have the following numeric input in my shiny app:

```
numericInput(
 inputId = "beta",
 label = "beta:",
 value = 0.05,
 step = 0.01
),
```

Is it possible to display in web browser "beta" as Greek symbol instead of string "beta"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
numericInput(
  inputId = "beta",
  label = HTML("&beta;:"),
  value = 0.05,
  step = 0.01
)
```

so replace beta by `&beta;` and it should render in the browser as β. `HTML` is used to mark the text so shiny doesnt performing escaping.

EDIT: to carry out more involved operations [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is useful. Here is an example of a `ui.R` calling the MathJax library:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("New Application"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$head( tags$script(src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full", type = 'text/javascript'),
               tags$script( "MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});", type='text/x-mathjax-config')
    ),
    numericInput(
      inputId = "beta",
      label = HTML("$$ \\beta_1 $$"),
      value = 0.05,
      step = 0.01
    )
  ),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I specify index? In base R I would use expression(beta[1]).

Comment: After deploying of App, the features of MathJax get lost :(. What can I do to keep it working also after deploying?

Comment: @And By deploying do you mean to shinyapps.io? I amm not sure what version of shiny server they are running. It may be best to ask https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users

Comment: @jdharrison exactly, deployApp(<NameOfApp>)!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same as in base R, where you use `expression(beta)`. I haven't tried that in shiny, but it should work.